# How can we use RowReduce with a modulous AND variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

We can use `RowReduce` with a field.  For example, we state

```
RowReduce[{{1,3,5},{0,1,2}},Modulous->23]
```

...which then returns:

```
{{1,0,22},{0,1,2}}
```

...So we will have effectively solved a linear system in a field.

**THE QUESTION**

Can we somehow use this to solve a system with variables, i.e. solve a symbolic system?
As an example, I would like to somehow solve:

```
RowReduce[{{1,3,a},{0,1,b}},Modulous->23]
```

The idea is that we should get a result essentially stating something like:

```
{{1,0,a - 3b},{0,1,b}}
```

or possibly even better:

```
{{1,0,a + 20b},{0,1,b}}
```

The first result is just the solution without the `modulous` included.  I'm wondering if there is some way to get the second result.

Comment: `RowReduce[{{1, 3, a}, {0, 1, b}}]` gives `{{1, 0, a - 3 b}, {0, 1, b}}`. All you seem to want is for each element of this to be reduced by the modulus?

Comment: @bills:  Sort of.  The problem that I have is that if I don't use a field, the values/coefficients are astronomically large.  So I'd like to find a way to work with smaller coefficients, if possible.  In the end, the results I get from this particular piece of linear algebra will be used in a field anyways.

Comment: Check the nb [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/). See section "Linear Algebra in a Galois field"

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:  It seems to have the solution I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, I don't have the mathematical background to understand a Groebner Basis.  I would be grateful if someone could essentially convert this code into something that works with integers modulo $p$.

Comment: Essentially converted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comment, this is based on  "Linear Algebra in a Galois field" from the notebook avaliable [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/). (Given its age, one might be surprised at how often I seem to need it).

Packaged code:

```
rowReduceModP[mat_?MatrixQ, p_] /; PrimeQ[p] := Module[
  {n = Length[mat[[1]]], z, newvars, gb},
  newvars = Array[z, n];
  gb = GroebnerBasis[mat.newvars, newvars, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions, Modulus -> p];
  Reverse[Outer[D, gb, newvars]]
  ]
```

Example:

```
mat = {{1, 3, a}, {0, 1, b}};
rowReduceModP[mat, 23]

(* Out[42]= {{1, 0, a + 20 b}, {0, 1, b}} *)
```